# Concatenate string with ASCII

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I want to achieve something like this:
(A) (B) (C) (D)... (I) (J)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    battlefield[i][0] = "(" + (64 + i) + ")";
```

I'v up with an idea to just put ASCII value into String, but it causes error:

> Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

if I try to compile it I got

> error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers

Basicly, the only way to make this compile is to add to_string before (64+i), but then I got something like:
(65) (66) (67), while I want letters which are under those ASCII values

Comment: What type is `battlefield`?

Comment: `"(" + (64 + i) + ")"` that expression is not doing anything close to what you probably wanted. Please update your question with the requested type of `battlefield`.

Comment: string battlefield[11][11];

Comment: Why using a 2D array ?

Comment: @AGasior You can use `battlefield[i][0] = std::string("(") + (64 + i) + ")";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert string literals to `std::string` before using `operator+`. A way of doing this

```
std::vector<std::string> battlefield(10);

for (char i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    battlefield[i]  = "(";
    battlefield[i] += 'A' + i;
    battlefield[i] += ")";
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea291d8592303745)

Answer (score 1):

Your concatenation expression is incorrect, because it mixes types:

```
"(" + (64 + i) + ")"
```

You can fix it by making the middle part `(64 + i)` a single-character string instead of an `int`:

```
battlefield[i][0] = "(" + string(1, 64+i) + ")";
```

Constructor `string(1, 64+i)` makes a string from one repetition (first parameter) of character `64+i` (second parameter). With this expression C++ has enough information to construct string objects from `"("` and `")"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd be inclined to:

1. Use zero-based indexing
2. Use the character literal 'A' as a base in order to make the conversion explicit.
3. hoist the generation of the string into a small function

Something like this:

```
#include <string>

auto& make_entry(std::string& cell, int index)
{
  cell += '(';
  cell += char('A' + index);
  cell += ')';
  return cell;
}

int main()
{
  std::string battlefield[10][1];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    make_entry(battlefield[i][0], i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
battlefield[i][0] = std::string("(") + (char) ('A'+i) + std::string(")");
```

The reason of the error message is that, when you write `"("`, you are using a raw, C-style `char*`, and you cannot add two pointers (what your error message says). By using the `std::string` constructor, you are forcing values to be treated as strings, and then the `+` operator works for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the ASCII character *contiguous* layout for alphabetical characters, writing a `for` loop with a `char` index going from `'A'` to `'J'`, and concatenating the current character to the result string.
During the concatenation, you can add the parentheses `(` and `)` as well.

E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string result;

    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'J'; ++ch) {
        result += '(';
        result += ch;
        result += ')';
    }

    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

---

**EDIT** If you want a `vector<string>`, you can modify the aforementioned code, using something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;

    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'J'; ++ch) {
        string s;
        s += '(';
        s += ch;
        s += ')';
        v.push_back(s);
    }

    for (auto const& s : v) {
        cout << s << ' ';
    }
}
```